# Разные классы и вызов методов (python3, PyQt5)

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qt-designer

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться с вызовом методов из одного класса в другой.

В примере есть два класса. Первый - это экран с кнопкой и текстом из `Qt Designer`, второй - функция секундомера, по нажатию на кнопку запускается секундомер.

Когда у меня только один класс, то я смог запустить секундомер, но когда я пытаюсь сделать 2 класс - тут я начинаю плыть.

````
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QApplication


class Display1_Ui(object):
    def setupUi1(self, Form1):
        Form1.setObjectName("Form")
        Form1.resize(400, 300)
        self.pushButton1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form1)
        self.pushButton1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 240, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton1.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form1)
        self.label1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 90, 47, 13))
        self.label1.setObjectName("label")

        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(lambda: Display1.prSome(Display1))
        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(lambda: Display1.start_timer(Display1))

        self.retranslateUi(Form1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form1)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form1):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form1.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Display1"))
        self.pushButton1.setText(_translate("Form", "Start"))
        self.label1.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel"))

class Display1(QWidget, Display1_Ui):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi1(self)
        self.Display1_Ui = Display1_Ui()

        self.tics = 0
        self.increment = 1000
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_time)

    def prSome(self):
        print('0')
        self.Display1_Ui.label1.setText('1')

    def update_time(self):
        self.tics += self.increment
        h = self.tics // 3600000
        m = (self.tics // 60000) % 60
        s = (self.tics / 1000) % 60
        self.label1.setText(f'{h:02d}:{m:02d}:{s:05.2f}')
        print((f'{h:02d}:{m:02d}:{s:05.2f}'))

    def start_timer(self):
        print('1')
        if self.Display1_Ui.pushButton1.text() == 'Start':
            print('2')
            self.pushButton1.setText('Stop')
            self.timer.start(self.increment)
        else:
            print('3')
            self.timer.stop()
            self.pushButton1.setText('Start')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui1 = Display1_Ui()
    ui1.setupUi1(Form1)
    Form1.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не изменяйте код, сгенерированный `Qt Designer`. Создайте другой класс,
который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QApplication


class Display1_Ui(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):                                             # setupUi Form
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.pushButton1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 240, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton1.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 90, 47, 13))
        self.label1.setObjectName("label")

#        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(lambda: Display1.prSome(Display1))
#        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(lambda: Display1.start_timer(Display1))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Display1"))
        self.pushButton1.setText(_translate("Form", "Start"))
        self.label1.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel"))


class Display1(QWidget, Display1_Ui):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
#        self.Display1_Ui = Display1_Ui()

        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(self.prSome)                  # ?
        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(self.start_timer)

        self.tics = 0
        self.increment = 1000
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_time)

    def prSome(self):
        print('0')
#        self.Display1_Ui.label1.setText('1')
        self.label1.setText('1')

    def update_time(self):
        self.tics += self.increment
        h = self.tics // 3600000
        m = (self.tics // 60000) % 60
        s = (self.tics / 1000) % 60
        self.label1.setText(f'{h:02d}:{m:02d}:{s:05.2f}')
        print((f'{h:02d}:{m:02d}:{s:05.2f}'))

    def start_timer(self):
        print('1')
#        if self.Display1_Ui.pushButton1.text() == 'Start':
        if self.pushButton1.text() == 'Start':
            print('2')
            self.pushButton1.setText('Stop')
            self.timer.start(self.increment)
        else:
            print('3')
            self.timer.stop()
            self.pushButton1.setText('Start')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#    Form1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    Form1 = Display1()                                               # !!!
#    ui1 = Display1_Ui()
#    ui1.setupUi1(Form1)
    Form1.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: огромное спасибо! Как всегда выручил!

Comment: @dutik пожалуйста